# Utility or command line function for advanced volume control in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio

I'm looking for a way to take control of my sound output in Windows 7.

If I have my headphones and speakers set up with one plugged into the back and one in the front, is there an easy way to assign certain software to output to my speakers and other software to output to my headphones? Is it possible to script it?

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible, as your headphones are connected to the speakers and take their input from them. Instead you can use a splitter or similar equipment and use both simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on your board's firmware. Some boards will support different sends between front and rear audio- Mostly newer ones, though. You can probably script it, but it'll be a good bit of work.

Comment: Could you provide any possible solutions?